# Converta string em uma classe C #

Tags: c#, .net

Estou fazendo uma integração com uma API em SOAP, em um dos métodos preciso passar como parâmetro um valor de uma classe da API, o problema é que recebo esse parâmetro no formato String e preciso convertê-lo para a classe proprietária Token da API. Tentei usar o código abaixo sem sucesso, onde recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'WebService.Token'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Nota: tentei adicionar o elemento implícito, mas não foi possível.

Meu código:

```
 NFeClient client = new();
    
    var result = client.SendOperation(arq);

//error converting string to Token class
    Token token = Convert.ChangeType(result.ReturnCode, typeof(string)); 
    var result = client.SendFile(token);
    
    Class that will receive the parameter:
    public partial class NFeClient : ServiceModel.ClientBase<WebService.INFe>, WebServiceTransben.INFe
    {
        public WebService.RetornoOfint SendFile(Token token)
        {
            return base.Channel.SendFile(token);
        } 
    }
    
    private string ReturnCodeField;
    public string ReturnCode
    {
            get
        {
            return this.ReturnCodeField;
        }
            set
        {
            this.ReturnCodeField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois desse codigo aqui, so inicializar e passar o token que vai

```
  public Token ReturnCode{get;set;}
```